# how to get windows console height?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, height

That is number of lines in the console ?

I know `SetConsoleWindowInfo()` but I can't find anywhere sheet for corresponding `GetConsoleWindowInfo()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo (GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);

//use csbi.dwSize for the rows and columns...
```

If you're on Vista and up you can use the ["Ex"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) form of this as well.

Comment: The screen buffer is much larger than the window, though. If you want to just get the (potentially smaller) window size, use csbi.srWindow instead.