# How to show a long usage information with "Press any key to continue" message?

Tags: c, windows, console-application, windows-console

Sorry, this might be a simple question, but I can't find a solution to that. I have a console application, which has several parameters. I show a usage information, how to use the application correctly, but since I have to explain each parameter it is very long. The whole usage won't fit in the console window.

So how can I display only that much from the usage which fits to actual window size?

A good example is `cmd`. If you open a command prompt, and then type `cmd /?` the usage information will be shown, but it will only show that much of the usage which will fit to the actual window size, and then waits for a keypress. If the window is small, you have to press a key 7 times. But if you make the console window bigger you have to press a key less.

So my question, how can I achieve this?

Comment: The `Press any key to continue` prompt can be triggered with `system("pause")`. Open `cmd.exe`, type `pause` and see what happens.

Comment: Show general options with `/?` only, and full help with `/? topic1`, `/? topic2` etc.

Comment: @szczurcio: I know that, but I assume this behaviour is done somehow else, since if the window size changes, the message will be displayed less.

Comment: @Jongware: That's an option too, but I like to use the method cmd uses. How does cmd do that?

Comment: It probably begins with asking the console window how big it is.

Comment: @Jongware: Probably, but I don't know which APIs to use. If I could see an example, it would be helpful, but I have no Idea where to begin.

Comment: Google suggests this SO question (not a total surprise): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921152/how-to-get-windows-console-height Note the note - perhaps it ought to be integrated in the answer, or added as a standalone answer.

Comment: Pipe the output through a pager like less.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *how* you would execute it, but what you need is a [pager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager).

I haven't tested it, but [here](http://www.computerhope.com/morehlp.htm) it says the `more` command is available in MS-DOS and most Windows versions (Windows 95, 98, ME, NT, 2000, XP, Vista, 7 & 8).

If you were running it standalone, you'd do `echo some-long-text | more`. I don't know how you'd use this from your own program, but that should be the way (I imagine there should be something like POSIX's `system()` syscall to run a command).