# How to get terminal size using ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

I thought that if I write the code like this, I'd adjust the terminal size and type any number, and it would output the changed terminal size value, but it always outputs to the initial value, what's the problem?

*p.s : It's windows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main(){
    initscr();
    while(1){
        clear();
        printw("[y:%d / x:%d]\n", getmaxy(stdscr), getmaxx(stdscr));
        refresh();
        getch();
        endwin();
        initscr();
    }
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get windows console height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921152/how-to-get-windows-console-height)

Comment: There's not enough information about the configuration to answer the question.